# Polymorphism (types)

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

These are some lines from “Thinking in C++” vol 1 (page 716 para2)by Bruce Eckel:

"Polymorphism is a feature that cannot
be viewed in isolation (like const or a switch statement, for
example), but instead works only in concert, as part of a “big
picture” of class relationships. People are often confused by other,
non-object-oriented features of C++, like overloading and default
arguments, which are sometimes presented as object-oriented.
Don’t be fooled; if it isn’t late binding, it isn’t polymorphism."

I am not able to get this clearly .Does he mean that  there is no such thing like Compile time Polymorphism?

Comment: Seems he at least ignored static polymorphism there.

Answer (score 2):

> Does he mean that there is no such thing like Compile time Polymorphism?

No. He means that, like the C++ standard, he's using the term "polymorphism" specifically to refer to dynamic (runtime) polymorphism, which C++ supports through inheritance and virtual functions.

C++ also supports what some would call "static (compile-time) polymorphism" or "generics" through templates and function overloads. In the context of C++, we tend not to use the term "polymorphism" for that, to avoid confusion with the standard, and rather different, meaning of that term.

Comment: "Don’t be fooled; if it isn’t late binding, it isn’t polymorphism" What does this means?

Comment: @shourya: "late binding" basically means deciding which function to call at the time the function is called; so it can use information that wasn't available earlier. In C++, that's done with virtual functions; calling one uses the dynamic type of the object to decide which override of the function to call.

Answer (score 0):

He is saying the following.

This is an example of polymorphism

```
class A
{
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Base class" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
    virtual void foo() override { std::cout << "Derived class" << std::endl; }
};
```

This is just overloading, which he is saying he doesn't consider to be OOP

```
// 3 overloads of a function
int foo(int x);
int foo(double x);
int foo(int x, double y);
```

Comment: What confuses me is :"if it isn’t late binding, it isn’t polymorphism."